# How can i fix code in jQuery.validator

Tags: jquery, validation

I want to check validation when user sign up. so, code is

```
  <span class="input_label">
  <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" required="required">
  <label>FIRST NAME *</label>
  </span>
```

and use jQuery.validator.

after that code is appeared

```
<span class="input_label">
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" required="required">
<label>FIRST NAME *</label>
</span>
<div for="firstname" class="tooltip">Please enter your first name</div>
```

class="tooltip" is i add   **errorClass: 'tooltip', errorElement: 'div',**

How do i have to do.. if I insert code **Please enter your first name**  in  tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the messages parameter for the validate() function config.

```
$('#form_id').validate({
   messages: {
      firstname: "Please enter your first name"
   },
   errorClass: 'tooltip',
   errorElement: 'div'
});
```

You could also use the errorPlacement parameter to programatically position the new element as needed.